# Realm: get collection of objects through 3 models

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm trying to find all rows through 3 models with relationships.

User 1-M Day
Day 1-M Event

```
class User extends RealmObject {
    String id;
    RealmList<Day> days;
}
class Day extends RealmObject {
    String id;
    RealmList<Event> events;
}
class Event extends RealmObject {
    String id;
    String issueId;
}
```

I want to get all events by issueId for current User;

For example: find all events with issueId = "TZB-1" for User with id = 1

I'm stuck on this:

```
User realmUser = mRealm.where(User.class).equalTo("id", userId).findFirst();
RealmList<Week> realmWeeks = realmUser.getWeeks();
```

I don't want to check each week in loop. Is there way to find events from selected weeks without loop?

In SQL it will be something like this:

```
select events.*
from users
left join days on users.id = days.user_id
left join events on days.id = events.day_id
where users.id = 1
and events.issue_id = "TZB-1"
```

**Update 1**
As a temporary solution I've found next example:
manually keep track of backlink to the User model, like that

```
class Event extends RealmObject {
        String id;
        String issueId;
        User user;
}
```

That allow to get all events this way:

```
RealmResults<Event> events = realm.where(Event.class).equalTo("user.id", userId).equalTo("issueId", issueId).findAll();
```

But that solution makes me to change a lot of code.

Comment: Backlink (`@LinkingObjects`) is currently in beta but has been released. Backlink queries will soon follow (currently in final review).

Comment: You could do `mRealm.where(User.class).equalTo("id", userId).findAll().where(User.class).equalTo("days.events.id", "TZB-1").findAll()`. If `User.id` is unique, then the first `findAll()` will return a `RealmResults` with one object.

Comment: @geisshirt but it will return User object. But I need RealmResults of Event object. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: You are correct. The LinkingObject feature and querying them will definitely help you. We are currently working on the final bits.